# Networking: Host a game on lan like game ranger

Tags: networking, virtualbox, vpn

am trying to create my own lan host server using drivers and adapter software rather than installing already made vpn.

i created a chat room using playitt,gg server:ip it connects to my server.exe from anywere over the internet.

now I tested a few VPN **Softether clients and server**
**Radmin VPN.**
they all work.

=
if i host a game from vmware than my pc in game multiplayer screen i cannot se the hosted game.

if i host from pc than vmware is able to see hosted games.

can anybody tell me what will it take to make this work manually so that the game detects hosted games in lan.

am trying to make something like gameranger software but am giving it a start.

Comment: This seems like a complicated question, could you make it more clear what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: i will edit my question check post one again